# Tableau - Both count and Percentage in Measure Values

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

I got a sheet that contain stacked bars of 2 measure values like the picture above(It's not mine but it's similar).

[image: Stacked Bars]

My question is, if there is any way to show both count and percentage of each stacked bar.
My data looks like picture below.

[image: Data]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While importing data into tableau don't import total column (it is redundant here).  By posting your data you have made it clear that you have data reshaping issue.  Proceed like this-

**Step-1**  While importing/connecting to worksheet, click app1 and app2 columns and then `pivot` them both.  screenshot

[image]

Rename these fields as per taste.  I have re-named these as `app name` and `val` respectively.

**Step-2** Create a calculated field as

```
{FIXED [App name]: sum([val])}/{sum([val])}
```

and build a view like this.  (Format calculation1 as percentage)

[image]

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response sir! I added some of my data to the post. Note that Total = App1 + App2. In stacked bars i want to show the count of App1 and App2 and theirs percentages. I tried your answer but the calculation for the App1 is included in the App2 also.

Comment: OH! in that case you'll have calculate the percentages as LOD.  Let me work it out.  I will probably add another solution and then delete this one.

Comment: See revised answer, please.  and don't address me as Sir.  call me Anil.

Comment: I am glad that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can also overlay a line graph or a semi-transparent area graph

You do this by using 'Dual-Axis' - after you have your original graph (the bar graph in your picture), you drag the same measure to the far **right** y-axis and drop it there.

You should now get a pill box looking ( measure | measure ) in your columns.
Use the dropdown on one of the ( measure | measure ) to change it to add table calculation - select 'Percent of Total' and compute using 'Table Down.'

From now on, the 'Percentage' measure will have a delta sign by it (triangle).

In your marks Pane, you will now have 2 Marks. They will be set to 'Automatic' and your graph will probably look like a dot graph. Change the counts one to a bar graph, change the percentage to line or area and if you are not interested in breakdown of count, as this is redundant, remove the measure on 'Colors.'

You can click on colors of the count Mark and change opacity and color.

[image]