# Showing absolute and percentage values in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I want to show both absolute and percentage value in a single view in the form of a matrix.
In the below view I am trying to add one more column showing values as percentages of total

Got hint here but not able to replicate:[Tableau - Both count and Percentage in Measure Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64693619/tableau-both-count-and-percentage-in-measure-values)

[image]

The data is like this

[image]

can any one please suggest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that difficult.  I recreated a data like yours,

[image]

Follow these steps

- Add `slide` on rows
- Add number of records in text on marks card
- Add table calculation on this field -> `percent of total`.  The view will look like this

[image]

- Notice a small triangle in 'no of records' field.  That indicates that it is table calculation
- Add number of records field once again to text. (*Tip:  Double click the field `number of records` to add it to view directly*)

[image]

- Reorder as you like

[image]

or with totals

[image]

Comment: I was rather selecting percentage of table from Analysis tab and then double click on Number of records puts in vertically down not in new columns. Thanks for helping me out.